# How to write web service stream data to a file in local directory

Tags: c#

When I call a web service it outputs data with CSV format.

Call web service:

```
https://www.rate-exchange.com/rates/api/v1/rates/USD.csv?quote=EUR&quote=GBP&fields=all
```

Its output as follows:

```
base_currency,currency,date,bid,ask,midpoint,high_bid,high_ask,low_bid,low_ask
USD,EUR,2014-12-23T21:00:00+0000,0.81875,0.81885,0.81880,0.82199,0.82208,0.81658,0.81667
USD,GBP,2014-12-23T21:00:00+0000,0.64275,0.64284,0.64280,0.64569,0.64577,0.64064,0.64071
```

Questions:
Can I have a code snippet in C# to write the output stream to a file `rate.csv` at `c:\temp`? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Jeff Li` you have the returned data already.. why can't you save that data to a file..? this is quite simple and I can't believe that you are having difficulty saving the output to a file.. perhaps you need to read up and practice some things found here [C# Basic Tutorials](http://www.dotnetperls.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If the service returns simple string:

```
string data = client.GetCsv();
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("c:\csv.txt"))
{
    sw.WriteLine(data);
}
```

If your csv file doesn't have new line chars:

```
string lines[] = data.split(Environment.NewLine);
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("c:\csv.txt"))
{
    for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(lines[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: his file will have `,` comma's as a delimiter so there will be no new line chars